# How do I detect how close UIView view is to the other UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, frame, bounds

Is there a magic method that accepts two views and returns how close they are to one another (perhaps the x and y distances)? Or is this something that must be done manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually. As long as there is no transform applied to the views, it shouldn't be that hard to write some code that would calculate the distance between the 2 view's frame rectangles.

Thinking out loud here:

If you can't draw a vertical and horizontal line in the space between the 2 views frame rectangles, the distance will be the x distance or y distance between the nearest sides.

If you can draw both a horizontal line and a vertical line between the views (they don't overlap in either the x dimension or the y dimension) then the distance between the 2 views will be the pythagorean distance between their nearest corners.

Answer (score 4):

To get the magical method you're looking for you should write a category on UIView:

```
// UIView+distance.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (distance)
-(double)distanceToView:(UIView *)view;
@end


// UIView+distance.m
#import "UIView+distance.h"

@implementation UIView (distance)
-(double)distanceToView:(UIView *)view
{
    return sqrt(pow(view.center.x - self.center.x, 2) + pow(view.center.y - self.center.y, 2));
}
@end
```

You can call this function from a view like:

```
double distance = [self distanceToView:otherView];
```

Or between two views like:

```
double distance = [view1 distanceToView:view2];
```

You could also write categories for distance to closest edge, etc. The above formula is just the distance between two points, I used the center of each view.  For more information on categories see the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html).

Answer (score 1):

Must be done manually.

```
- (double)distance:(UIView*)view1 view2:(UIView*)view2
{
       double dx = CGRectGetMinX(view2) - CGRectGetMinX(view1);
       double dy = CGRectGetMinY(view2) - CGRectGetMinY(view1);

       return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
       or
       return sqrt(pow(dx, 2) + pow(dy, 2));
}
```

CGRectGetMinX() | CGRectGetMaxX() and CGRectGetMinY() | CGRectGetMaxY() can help you a lot.

Comment: That's not right. Why would you raise the difference in left edges of the views by the power of the difference in top edges of the views?

Comment: Igor, even that approach is not right. You are always calculating the distance between the left edges of both frames, and the distance between the tops of both frames. The problem is more complex than that. If the 2 frames overlap in 1 dimension, the answer will be the linear distance between the near edges in only 1 dimension. Only if the 2 views have white space between them in both dimensions do you need to calculate pythagorean distance, and then you need to figure out the nearest corners. See my post for a rough outline of how to solve the problem.